# What is "Factor" in Point Scale (Geo Nodes)?

Tags: geometry-nodes

If I want to use this node on the "Attribute" mode, how can I use it? what is it used for?
I tried to play by typing some built-in attributes next to the Factor input. It changed the scale but I still don't know how to use it. I mean how is the scale calculated?
The [manual](http://Use%20the%20values%20from%20the%20attribute%20to%20move%20each%20point%20by%20a%20different%20amount.) says:

> Use the values from the attribute to move each point by a different
> amount.

Why points should be moved? Is it about scaling or moving or both? or is it just my english?

I know how to use the "Vector" mode.

Comment: The link to the manual is broken, Do you mean this? [Point Scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_scale.html) 
But your quote is actually from [Point Translation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_translate.html). In the title of this question you wrote *Point Scale*. I think you confused them, didn't you?

Comment: @Blunder Yes, that's the link (point scale). If you read the subtitle (Attribute), you'll find the quote. Maybe it's confused in the manual. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this node to scale points by amount in a specific attribute. For example, I generated an attribute using **Attribute Proximity** node.  Attribute Proximity generates attribute based on distance between vertex and closest point in geometry, I called it "new_attr":

[image]

Next I scaled vertexes by this attribute. Of course, to view scale you need to have some instances distributed by them, so I distribute Suzannes.